# jqGrid can't render Spanish characters in column's names but CAN in other controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 3. I have the following configuration for the grid:

```
grid.jqGrid({
        data: pages,
        datatype: 'json',
        emptyrecords: 'No hay proyectos cargados',
        colNames: ["Código", "Descripción", "Rev", "Cliente", "Tipo"],
        colModel: [
                 { name: 'Codigo', index: 'Codigo', width: 100 },
                 { name: 'Descripcion', index: 'Descripcion asc, Descripcion', width: 200 },
                 { name: 'Rev', index: 'Rev', width: 100, align: "right" },
                 { name: 'Cliente', index: 'Cliente', width: 200, align: "right" },
                 { name: 'Tipo', index: 'Tipo', width: 200, align: "right" }
               ],
        rowNum: 10,
        pager: '#dPager',
        sortname: 'Codigo',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        beforeRequest: function() {
            if (pages.length === 0) {
                grid[0].p.page = 0;
            }
        },
        height: 'auto',
    });
```

The column names "Código" and "Descripción" display a weird symbol (a black diamond with a white question mark inside of it) instead of the "ó" characters.

For your information:

- There are other "ó" characters in the View that are rendered, which makes me believe it has nothing to do with the page's encoding (FYI, the DOCTYPE tag is the standard  that appears in the _Layout.cshtml).
- jqGrid itself does render the special "ó" character in other controls, *so long they appear in grid.locale-es.js*. So, for instance, the literal for "Page X of Y" is "Página X de Y", and if I change it for "óóóóóóóóó X de Y" it renders it properly.
- The same problem happens if I change, for instance, the emptyrecords entry with "óóóóóó".

Any ideas why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen because you have placed this script in a javascript file which doesn't have the correct encoding to match with your site.

So for example if your site is UTF-8, make sure that you have saved the .js file with UTF-8 with BOM.

- Open the .js file in Visual Studio and choose `File->Save As`
- Click on the down arrow next to the `Save` button
- Select `Save with Encoding ...`
- From the drop down list select `Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001`:

[image]

Comment: Great. Wouldn't have though about that. I'll add "learn about encoding" to my to-do list.